# How to check current running applications in Android?

Tags: android

I want to check current running applications in android programmatically, similar to how it shows 6 applications if we press and hold the **HOME** button.

I'm mostly interested in the application names.

Answer (score 52):

You can get current name package using

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) mContext
                .getSystemService(Activity.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        String packageName = am.getRunningTasks(1).get(0).topActivity
                .getPackageName();
```

You can use this package name to get current active application

Comment: Awesome answer. I was looking for this forever! This gives the task that the user is currently doing (program they are currently in). Great!

Comment: Requires permission: android.permission.GET_TASKS

Comment: The getRunningTasks method has been [truncated](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html) in the latest API for Android Lollipop. Do you have any suggestions on an alternative way to do this?

Comment: @prajitdas, the only workaround on a nonrooted device is to develop an accessiblity service (look [here](http://developer.android.com/training/accessibility/service.html) and [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/services.html)), which must be explicitly enabled by device's user.

Comment: BTW, on Android 5 you can even get the list of 0 size as a result of `getRunningTasks`, so get(0) raises the "IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0". This information comes from Google Play ANR reporting tool for a published application.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how can Fleksy keyboard do this without requiring an accessibility service to be enabled?

Answer (score 16):

You can check the processName of each element in the list to see if it's the process you're looking for. You can use this code

```
boolean isNamedProcessRunning(String processName){
 if (processName == null) 
  return false;

 ActivityManager manager = 
    (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
 List<RunningAppProcessInfo> processes = manager.getRunningAppProcesses();
 for (RunningAppProcessInfo process : processes)
 {
    if (processName.equals(process.processName))
    {
        return true;
    }
 }
 return false;
}
```

Answer (score 11):

**A long press of the HOME key brings up a list of recent (not necessarily running) tasks.**

`ActivityManager` has what you need.  Look at [`getRunningAppProcesses`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRunningAppProcesses%28%29) or [`getRunningTasks`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRunningTasks(int)).

You can view this information (and much more) by running `dumpsys activity` via 'adb shell'.

```
  Running processes (most recent first):
    App  #11: adj=fore /F 43fe7c20 233:com.android.browser/10004 (top-activity)
    App  #10: adj=bak  /B 43dcec80 190:android.process.media/10009 (bg-empty)
    App  # 9: adj=vis  /F 43f495c8 107:com.android.inputmethod.latin/10014 (service)
              com.android.inputmethod.latin.LatinIME<=ProcessRecord{43dbe0e8 59:system/1000}
    PERS # 8: adj=sys  /F 43dbe0e8 59:system/1000 (fixed)
    PERS # 7: adj=core /F 43f534c0 111:com.android.phone/1001 (fixed)
    App  # 6: adj=bak+1/B 43ea1f58 148:android.process.acore/10006 (bg-empty)
    App  # 5: adj=home /B 43f601c0 114:com.android.launcher/10000 (home)
    App  # 4: adj=bak+2/B 43f85128 133:com.android.settings/1000 (bg-empty)
    App  # 3: adj=bak+3/B 43eacae0 223:com.android.music/10029 (bg-empty)
    App  # 2: adj=bak+4/B 43dfc500 206:com.android.mms/10028 (bg-empty)
    App  # 1: adj=bak+5/B 43f8fcd0 166:com.android.alarmclock/10025 (bg-empty)
    App  # 0: adj=bak+6/B 43fcbe50 182:com.android.email/10008 (bg-empty)

  PID mappings:
    PID #59: ProcessRecord{43dbe0e8 59:system/1000}
    PID #107: ProcessRecord{43f495c8 107:com.android.inputmethod.latin/10014}
    PID #111: ProcessRecord{43f534c0 111:com.android.phone/1001}
    PID #114: ProcessRecord{43f601c0 114:com.android.launcher/10000}
    PID #133: ProcessRecord{43f85128 133:com.android.settings/1000}
    PID #148: ProcessRecord{43ea1f58 148:android.process.acore/10006}
    PID #166: ProcessRecord{43f8fcd0 166:com.android.alarmclock/10025}
    PID #182: ProcessRecord{43fcbe50 182:com.android.email/10008}
    PID #190: ProcessRecord{43dcec80 190:android.process.media/10009}
    PID #206: ProcessRecord{43dfc500 206:com.android.mms/10028}
    PID #223: ProcessRecord{43eacae0 223:com.android.music/10029}
    PID #233: ProcessRecord{43fe7c20 233:com.android.browser/10004}
```

Comment: i am talking about pro grammatically.