# a way to programmatically know when an application is in "opened" state on android?

Tags: java, android, service

I wanted to know if there's a way to programmatically get the "opened" application name or something from a background Service. Is it? Like let me give you an example:

```
if(Apps.FACEBOOK_STATUS_OPENED == currentApplication.getStatus()) { 
   ...
   do something in the service for this app 
}else if(Apps.WHATSAPP_STATUS_OPENED == currentApplication.getStatus()) {
   ...
   do another thing for this app
}...
```

Is there a way to listen to that? There must be.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why is this in the user's best interests?

Comment: @CommonsWare mm? because i need this functionality for an app i want to develope. Is there a way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done, forget what i asked. Found it here

[How to check current running applications in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3278895/how-to-check-current-running-applications-in-android)

Thanks anyway guys.