# Android, Learn about the application in the foreground

Tags: java, android, process, foreground

I want to know if it is possible to know the application in use by the user. Currently, I manage to get the list of active processes on the foreground but unfortunately it does not isolate the specific application for ca also taking applications in the status bar.

Here's what I use:

```
ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> appProcesses = activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
    for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo appProcess : appProcesses)
    {
        if(appProcess.importance == ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND)
        {
            Log.d("Executed app", "Foreground " +appProcess.processName + "\t\t ID: " + appProcess.pid);
        }
    }
```

Here is what I get:

> 11-09 18:12:56.645    8821-8821/company.test D/Executed app﹕
>   Foreground company.gillot.test         ID: 8821 11-09 18:12:56.645
>   8821-8821/company.test D/Executed app﹕ Foreground
>   android.process.acore      ID: 30279 11-09 18:12:56.645
>   8821-8821/company.test D/Executed app﹕ Foreground com.android.phone
>   ID: 197 11-09 18:12:56.645    8821-8821/company.test D/Executed app﹕
>   Foreground system      ID: 97

Anyone have an idea? I browse the forums and the android api but so far nothing specific property.

BONUS:

Thereafter I would avoid detected applications "system".

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you may mean check out this link:
[How to check current running applications in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3278895/how-to-check-current-running-applications-in-android)
or
 http://androidexample.com/Check_Current_Running_Activity_%7C_Task_%7C_Application_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=111&aaid=133
I hope this helps these are the methods I have used before.