# how to know when other app is launched in android

Tags: android, service, android-broadcast

Hi friend
 I am developing an app in android and i want to know when other application is launched . 
for example i want when users run -viber- i running some code in my app . (for example silent the phone or anything)

DRAW ON OTHER APPLICATION can help me or i should to run a service or broadcastReciver for this ?

for examle i want to run this code

```
AudioManager audio = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
            audio.setRingerMode(0);
```

when viber is launched  . 
anyone can help me ?
Thanks.

Comment: This answer may help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3278895/how-to-check-current-running-applications-in-android

Comment: this is useful but how i can knew that any app is launched ?

Comment: You may run a service with intervals for listening changes in the packagemanager or try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3290936/android-detect-when-other-apps-are-launched