# How to launch a lock screen that prevents the access to an application when it starts?

Tags: android, lockscreen

I'm trying to create a lock screen that prevents access to an application when it starts but I can't find answers. I'm not sure how to implement the code.
Also in most cases it's mentioned that it was deprecated in android 5.1 and higher.

(I´m working in android 7.1)

These are the links:

[Android, Detect when other apps are launched](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3290936/android-detect-when-other-apps-are-launched)

[How to check current running applications in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3278895/how-to-check-current-running-applications-in-android)

[how to know when other app is launched in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28764559/how-to-know-when-other-app-is-launched-in-android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create your background service for that , which will continuously monitor top app in device .

So first of all make a service which will start after your app launch .In your service , use this

```
ActivityManager mActivityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> RunningTask = mActivityManager.getRunningTasks(1);
ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo ar = RunningTask.get(0);
activityOnTop=ar.topActivity.getClassName();
```

activityOnTop will give you the current running app in your phone . Now show lock screen after getting top activity.