# Custom Keyboard Android get current App

Tags: android, keyboard

I wish to get name/packageName of current app using my customKeyboard service.

Is there anyway to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found answer in this topic: [How to check current running applications in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3278895/how-to-check-current-running-applications-in-android)

If app is running its obviosuly the one calling my keyboard.

Answer (score 4):

You have to rely on [getCurrentInputEditorInfo()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/InputMethodService.html#getCurrentInputEditorInfo()), a method in `InputMethodService`, to achieve this:

```java
String packageName = getCurrentInputEditorInfo().packageName;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
private String getApplicationName() {
    final PackageManager pm = mActivity.getApplicationContext()
            .getPackageManager();
    ApplicationInfo ai;
    String appName;
    try {
        ai = pm.getApplicationInfo(mActivity.getPackageName(), 0);
        appName = (String) pm.getApplicationLabel(ai);
    } catch (final NameNotFoundException e) {
        appName = "(unknown)";
    }
    return appName;
}
```

use this method to get Appname/Package name

Comment: This allowes me to get appname/package name (as long as I implemented it correctly) of my own app, I created keyboard service and wish to know which app uses it to write inside of that app.

Comment: Downvoted. This does not attempt to answer the question asked.