# How to know if certain process is running in a Android device?

Tags: android, linux, shell, jscript, testcomplete

We are working on TestComplete automation tool for automating Test scripts for android device. How to get to know all the processes running in a android device using shell script or TestComplete script?

Comment: This seems like a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3278895/how-to-check-current-running-applications-in-android

Comment: @Sipty: Not a duplicate. This question is about writing automated tests for Android, not writing Android apps.

Comment: Do you need  to check if a specific process is running (as the title says), or list all processes (as the post says)?

Answer (score 0):

This lists all running processes *that were instrumented for TestComplete*:

```js
function Test()
{
  Mobile.SetCurrent("emulator-5554");
  var device = Mobile.Device();

  for (var i = 0; i < device.ChildCount; i++)
  {
    Log.Message(device.Child(i).ProcessName);
  }
}
```

To list ALL running process, you can use the `adb shell ps` command. You can run it from TestComplete like this:

```js
function Test()
{
  Mobile.SetCurrent("emulator-5554");

  var str = Mobile.Device().ShellExecute("ps");
  Log.Message("See Additional Info", str);
}
```

But you'll need to filter the command's output, because it looks like:

```
USER     PID   PPID  VSIZE  RSS     WCHAN    PC        NAME

root      1     0     9128   808   c02b4929 0806c150 S /init

root      2     0     0      0     c023172d 00000000 S kthreadd

system    1238  949   599324 84032 ffffffff b7503355 S system_server

u0_a12    1438  949   520712 56672 ffffffff b7503355 S com.android.systemui

u0_a2     1457  949   491816 32504 ffffffff b7503355 S android.process.acore
```