# Android : check whether Home key is pressed or not

Tags: android

Can anybody help me to find out, how can i find that whether the HOME key is pressed or not?
I want to take action based on it....

I am using   KeyEvent.isModifierKey(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME) to check whether home key is pressed or not....It always returns me false....

Can anybody help me to go ahead..

Thanks, Rakesh

Comment: You might try overriding onKeyDown and check for KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME. I think that I tested that at one point. I believe I got the call back for it. But I was unable to stop it from completing the 'Go To Home' action. You might be able to do something in addition though.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I detect user pressing HOME key in my activity?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208912/how-can-i-detect-user-pressing-home-key-in-my-activity)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this. Your application will not receive HOME key events.