# Close current activity on android Device's Home button click

Tags: android, android-launcher, android-homebutton

I don't want to allow application to run in background.
As user press Home button on android device, current activity should be finished.

Or when application is resumed, I would like to know that application has come foreground.

I have created receiver in the <application>  tag in the manifest file:

```
<receiver
        android:name=".HomeKeyReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Still this receiver is not getting called. If this receiver is called then I can close application.

Comment: check the answer in: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4784134/1434631  
And read also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2079691/overriding-the-home-button-how-do-i-get-rid-of-the-choice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the way for this is like,

when user press home button, current activity's pause method called.

after a second of activity goes in background , if no other activity is opened(i have used global boolean variable), then I broadcast the message to all activity to be closed.

So whichever activity is open, will be closed on that receiver.

It works for me. Hope so it could help you as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
protected void onUserLeaveHint() {
    super.onUserLeaveHint();
    finish();
}
```

And since it's a single activity you could work with `onPause()`, `onStop()` and `onResume()`.

Answer (score 0):

Check out `onUserLeaveHint()` of [`Activity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onUserLeaveHint%28%29) class.. 
Documentation says

> Called as part of the activity lifecycle when an activity is about to
>   go into the background as the result of user choice.

Also see `onUserInteraction()`.

Comment: I have checked this code but it is called also when I am moving to other activity.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only looking to force your activity to not run on background, and to be recreated every time, you have to override the onStop method:

```
enter code here

protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (!isFinishing()) {
        finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I would like to have it for application with multiple activities.