# Set Action for home button in android

Tags: android

How I can change working of home button in android? I want to when I click on home button I do some actions and after that application should go to background. How I can do that.

Comment: You want your action to happen only when you click on the home button, or any time your application should go to the background ?

Comment: Take a look at this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4783960/call-method-when-home-button-pressed-on-android)

Comment: every time when click home button

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write your own home screen. When the user presses HOME, they will get a choice of running your app or the built-in home screen. They can elect to choose one just this one time, or set either app as being their default from now on. Many will wonder why on Earth you decided to decided to implement a home screen.

Most developers care about any case where their activity moves to the background, in which case you can either use a lifecycle method (e.g., `onPause()`, `onStop()`) or try `onUserLeaveHint()`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried overriding onKeyDown()

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME) {
        // ENTER CODE HERE
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do it this way:

```
/* Handles item selections */
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:    
                    //You can do whatever you want here       
            Intent homeInt = new Intent(this, SomeActivity.class);
            startActivity(homeInt);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```