# Method unnecessarily getting called?

Tags: java, android, performance, inheritance, methods

I have a BaseActivity that gets extended by every other activity. The thing is, I have the music muted whenever the user leaves (onPause) the activity. I also stop listening for telephone calls. **The problem is, `onPause` is getting called whenever the user switches between activities, meaning the app is unnecessarily muting and stopping `telephonymanager`, even though it should only be muting and stopping `telephonymanager` if the user were to leave the app.:**

```
@Override
    protected void onPause() {

        Log.v(TAG, "IN onPause!");
        // unregister phone listener to telephony manager
        tManager.listen(phoneStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE);

        mute();

        super.onPause();
    }
```

Now say I switch between `public class myClass extends BaseActivity` and switch to `public class myOtherClass extends BaseActivity`. This switch is **unnecessarily** executing `onPause`, even though I only want `onPause` to be called **when the user leaves the app**. What should I do?

Thanks for the expert advice,

Rich

Comment: Write the code for muting music player inside your MusicplayActiviti instead of writing in BaseActivity

Comment: Sounds like it's working as intended. The `onPause` method of an `Activity` gets called when another `Activity` comes into the foreground: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle

Comment: @CoryCharlton So what do you suggest I use. My intention is to mute and stop the `telephoney manager` when the user exits the app. Since I can't use `onPause`, what should I use?

Comment: @Rich see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding you are muting your music playing in onPause of BaseActivity, instead of that write it inside your Music play activity

Ex :

```
 public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

     @Override
     public void onPause(){
      //do things that common for all activities
     }
    }


public void MusicPlayActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

 @Override
 public void onPause(){
 music.mute()
 }
}
```

This will work

**UPDATE**

There are few ways to detect whether your application is running in the background, but only one of them is completely reliable:
Track visibility of your application by yourself using `Activity.onPause`, `Activity.onResume` methods. Store "visibility" status in some other class.

***Example***
 : Implement custom Application class (note the isActivityVisible() static method):

public class MyApplication extends Application {

```
  public static boolean isActivityVisible() {
    return activityVisible;
  }  

  public static void activityResumed() {
    activityVisible = true;
  }

  public static void activityPaused() {
    activityVisible = false;
  }

  private static boolean activityVisible;
}
```

Register your application class in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<application
    android:name="your.app.package.MyApplication"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
```

Add `onPause` and `onResume` to every Activity in the project (you may create a common ancestor for your Activities if you'd like to, but if your activity is already extended from MapActivity/ListActivity etc. you still need to write the following by hand):

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
  super.onResume();
  MyApplication.activityResumed();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
  super.onPause();
  MyApplication.activityPaused();
}
```

[ActivityLifecycleCallbacks](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks.html) were added in API level 14 (Android 4.0). You can use them to track whether an activity of your application is currently visible to the user. Check [Cornstalks' answer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks.html) below for the details.

Comment: OnPause only gets called when the activity is finished, rather than the app. How can I detect whether the app is finished?

Comment: means you want to mute your audio when app goes background, isn't it ?

Answer (score 0):

From your comments you only want to stop the music when the last `Activity` of your application is exiting. Overriding the [`finish()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish%28%29) method of your `BaseActivity` like this should accomplish what you want:

```
@Override
public void finish() {
    super.finish();

    if (isTaskRoot()) {
        // This is the last Activity in the stack so mute your music here...
    }
}
```

Actually you probably want [`onDestroy()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy%28%29) or [`onStop()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onStop%28%29) as I'm not sure `finish()` executes unless you call it but the idea is the same:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    if (isTaskRoot()) {
        // This is the last Activity in the stack so mute your music here...
    }
}
```

Here's info on [`isTaskRoot()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#isTaskRoot%28%29):

> Return whether this activity is the root of a task. The root is the first activity in a task.
>
> **Returns**
>
> True if this is the root activity, else false.

Comment: Okay, so if I am on Activity A and I exit out, will `finish()` get called? And `finish()` shouldn't be called if I just switch from Activity A to  Activity B. Thanks

Comment: `isTaskRoot` will only see if it's the last activity in the activityStack. But that's not what I want, instead I want the app to do the mute code when the user exits out. It doesn't matter when or where the user exits out, but when he/she does, I want to mute it

Comment: @Rich `finish()` will get called when the user presses the back button. See this post for the home button: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4783960/call-method-when-home-button-pressed-on-android from your last comment though you now need to handle the cases where the user launches a new app from the notification, etc.

Comment: Okay, so I tried `finish()`, but the same issue is there. It gets called every activity also...What should I try next? I will mark you best answer and like your post once I get this. Thanks!

Comment: So I think these only get called when the **activity** is finished, rather than the app. How can I detect whether the **app** is finished?

Comment: @Rich, yes these are all `Activity` lifecycle methods. The `Application` doesn't have lifecycle methods like this. There are hacks such as this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8489993/check-android-application-is-in-foreground-or-not but I wouldn't recommend them. They also don't directly solve your problem because the `Application` can run without any activities (ie: if a `Service` is running).

Comment: So what do you suggest I do?

Comment: Is it impossible to properly check if an app has been exited out of? Because I see games with multiple activities do it all the time? When there is music playing, and I press the home button, the app silents itself

Comment: How does that work? And can I use the same kind of code?

Comment: @Rich They probably do like I noted in an earlier comment and also watch for the user pressing the home button as outlined here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4783960/call-method-when-home-button-pressed-on-android I'm not sure there's going to be a single, one size fits all, solution for what you want to achieve and will need to cover all aspects (ie: user presses back button on last activity [finish solution in my answer should cover this], user presses home button, user launches another application from a notification, etc.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94855/discussion-between-rich-and-cory-charlton).