# How to simulate a long click on a physical android home button?

Tags: java, android, selenium, appium

I'm doing automation on a real android device with appium and java.

Is there any way I can simulate a long press on the physical home button of the device?

Comment: this may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4783960/call-method-when-home-button-pressed-on-android

Comment: try TouchAction action = new TouchAction();
action.longPress(webElement).release().perform();