# Go back to previous acitivity stack after pressing Home in Android launcher

Tags: android, android-activity, android-launcher, activity-stack

I am developing a custom launcher/home-screen, thus I am able to hand home-press events.

Sometimes I want it to intercept Home-presses without affecting the visible activity-stack so to speak. When I press home, however, I get to the launcher stack I suppose, but what I want to do then is get back to the last visited activity stack that was shown right before I pressed home. How can I do that?

How can I retrieve and show the activity that was visible right before I pressed home?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4783960/call-method-when-home-button-pressed-on-android

Comment: I can intercept home in onResume(). Though at that point I want to exit that launcher activity immediately and return to the previous activity.

Comment: I'd say you could keep a tracking of the the previous activity in the current activity and start it onResume

Comment: In onResume(), how can I know which was the previous activity?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4038479/android-go-back-to-previous-activity

Comment: I don't think this is what I want because I am traversing across different apps. Not only my internal activity stack.

Comment: What actually happens if I call finish() in a Launcher-app?

Comment: If you have no other activity running it will send the app to background. If, for example, you are in the Main activity, you navigate to your second activity, and you call finish() in the second activity you will go back to the main activity

Comment: But when I am in main and do finish() in onResume I get empty black screen. I never go back to any other previous activity stack belonging to some other app. Why?

Comment: onResume works similarly like onCreate so if you call finish() in it you will close the activity

Comment: Yes it will close, but then where do I go if launcher (home-screen) closes?