# How to Disable Home button like When playing video and press lock screen button

Tags: java, android

I need to disable Home button like when you playing Video and then you press lock screen button (Video still play and you cannot press Home button or show Notification bar)

Have anyone know how can do like that?

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4783960/call-method-when-home-button-pressed-on-android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4783960/call-method-when-home-button-pressed-on-android)

Comment: thx. i will check it