# Home key Handled in Ice Cream Sandwich

Tags: android

Through that code i am success to handle HomeKey in below 4.0 version but i have problem in handling Homekey in upper 4.0 version. so please help me to solve that issue to handle HomeKey press in upper 4.0 version.because it is not disable Home press.

```
@Override
    public void onAttachedToWindow() 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) 
      {
        super.onAttachedToWindow();
        this.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD);
             getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
}

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

As @j__m said, `TYPE_KEYGUARD` is no longer supported. There are many other ways which have been discussed on other questions but don't work in latest API level. I'll save you the effort and would like to share some search, trial and error that I did. I tried many method but none of them worked for me in API level 17. I tried answers on

[Call method when home button pressed on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4783960/call-method-when-home-button-pressed-on-android),

[Detect home button press in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8881951/detect-home-button-press-in-android) and

Some of the ones I tried( including above answers) and **didn't work** were:

1. Using **`keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME`** in many ways as
   stated above. Now, if you read the documentation of
   [KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17756786/1306419), it says that `This key is handled by the
   framework and is never delivered to applications`. So its no more
   valid now.
2. I tried using **`onUserLeaveHint()`**. `The documentation says:
   Called as part of the activity lifecycle when an activity is about
   to go into the background as the result of user choice.`**`For example,
   when the user presses the Home key, onUserLeaveHint() will be
   called,`**`but when an incoming phone call causes the in-call Activity
   to be automatically brought to the foreground`.

   **If you are not calling any activity from within your current activity, where you are  detecting the home button then you might be
   able to use this approach.** The issue with that
   is that the method also gets called when you start an `Activity`
   from within the activity where you are calling `onUserleaveLint()`,
   as was my case. See [Android onBackPressed/onUserLeaveHint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6612058/android-onbackpressed-onuserleavehint/8749061#8749061) question for more. So its not sure that
   it would be call ONLY by pressing home button.

Finally the **following worked** for me :

Seeing [How to check current running applications in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3278895/how-to-check-current-running-applications-in-android), you can say that if yours is the recent task that is shown on long pressing the home button, then it was send to background.( i.e home button was pressed).

So, In your `onPause()` of the activity where you are trying to detect the home button pressed, you can check whether the application has been sent to background.

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    if (isApplicationSentToBackground(this)){
            // Home button pressed
        // Do what you want to do on detecting Home Key being Pressed 
    }
    super.onPause();
}
```

Function to check whether yours is the app which has been most recently sent to the background:

```
public boolean isApplicationSentToBackground(final Context context) {
    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<RunningTaskInfo> tasks = am.getRunningTasks(1);
    if (!tasks.isEmpty()) {
        ComponentName topActivity = tasks.get(0).topActivity;
        if (!topActivity.getPackageName().equals(context.getPackageName())) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Using this I was successfully able to detect the `Home Button` click. 
Hope this works for you as well.

Comment: You rock Shobhit Puri. Just change `topActivity` for `baseActivity`.

Answer (score 0):

`TYPE_KEYGUARD` is no longer supported for non-system apps.  The only way to handle the home key is to be the launcher.