# Home/Back button is pressed nothing is happened

Tags: android

How could I do that when the user presses the Home or Back button my app doesn't go to the background?
I tried this but it didn't work

```
@Override
protected void onUserLeaveHint() {
return;
}
```

Comment: Try this.
[Android onBackPressed/onUserLeaveHint](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6612058/android-onbackpressed-onuserleavehint)

Comment: Override onBackPressed method and keep it empty.

Comment: please post your code

Comment: you can't prevent the home button

Comment: @njzk2 But how then not custom lock screens can do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can prevent return by overriding `onBackPressed()` and not invoking its `super` method, but you cannot prevent the home button from triggering its actions.