# Method before home button

Tags: android, home-button

My android application is a client, and when someone click the home button, I want to send a message to the server, and when the user changes back to the application, I also want to send a message to the server. If I could overwrite the HOME button keyEvent, or any method which will be called **only** when the application will be put into background, I could send message and set a static variable in a singleton which will be checked every onStart(), so basically I just need to somehow "override" the HOME button.
I tried the followings:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME) {
        //...
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

It does simply not work. I put a breakpoint in it, but HOME button doesn't trigger this method at all. (Samsung Galaxy Ace, android 2.2.1).

I also tried to overrite the `onUserLeaveHint()` like this:

```
@Override
protected void onUserLeaveHint() {
    //...
    super.onUserLeaveHint();
}
```

But the problem is, this method will be called **not only** when I press HOME button or the application is interrupted, but when I just navigate to an other activity (and finish the current one).
Are there any solution to this problem?

Comment: Try to override your MainActivity's onPause().

Answer (score 4):

Might want to take a look at this [Android Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)

You are looking for onPause / onResume, based on the line

> or any method which will be called only when the application will be
>   put into background

That doc should explain how the stack works, which will allow you to accomplish this problem.

Comment: The problem with onPause, that this will be called, when I just simply change activity(and finish the current), not only when the application goes background. How to make difference between the two situation?

Comment: Unfortunately Android doesn't have a applicationDidEnterBackground like iOS does. IMO, you're best off keeping track of your activities active status to determine if it is going into background or going to a new activity. There are a lot of topics regarding this on SO, with a lot of different ideas. I suggest looking around to find what works best for you.

Comment: thanks the answer, at least I wont try to find something thast doesnt exists.

Answer (score 1):

There is not an day solution to this problem, because android does not let you override the home button. The easiest way around this is to pur your code in `onPause`, but of course this can be called without the home button being pressed.

The second (not accepted) answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6693896/home-key-press-event-listener) has an interesting solution, but I have not tried it so I am not sure if it works

Comment: unfortunately, it doesn't work with my phone properly, it's a bit unpredictable.