# how to check hold mode programmatically in android

Tags: android

I have an app and i want to check "hold mode/center button" pressed in Galaxy note. For example there is a built in function or listner for onBackPressed so is there any function for "hold mode" button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "center button" you mean the Home button, then the answer is you can't listen for the home button press.
If that's not the question, then please rephrase cause it's hard to know what you're asking.
This question appears to be a duplicate:

[Home key press Event Listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6693896/home-key-press-event-listener)