# How to differentiate between back button and home button presses

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-navigation

When my app starts, there is a start button. The user can start a fragment which setup time can't be neglected. When the user presses back on this fragment, his intention is probalby to leave the fragment, so it's wise to free the resources. However when he presses home (hardware home), his intention may be checking something and coming back. In this case I'd like to keep the data (not serialisable). How can I differentiate between the two cases?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18545014/differentiate-the-functionality-of-home-button-and-back-button-in-android-activi

Comment: @kalyan pvs: That question relates to activity stack, this question is about one fragment.

Answer (score 1):

While I was writing the question, I found a solution, though not the most beautiful (a flag needs to be kept). For both calls, the `onPause()`, `onStop()`, `onDestroy()`, `onDetach()` is called in both cases. The `getActivity().isChangingConfigurations()` returns false in both cases. But the `onSaveInstanceState()` is only called when the device is rotated *and* when the home is pressed. So:

- Back button

  ```
  isChangingConfigurations(): false
  onPause()
  onStop()
  onDestroy()
  onDetach()
  ```
- Home button

  ```
  isChangingConfigurations(): false
  onPause()
  onSaveInstanceState()
  onStop()
  onDestroy()
  onDetach()
  ```
- Rotate device

  ```
  isChangingConfigurations(): true
  onPause()
  onSaveInstanceState()
  onStop()
  onDestroy()
  onDetach()
  ```

Note: the fragment is not retained. Retaining it would alter the whole process.

Note 2: According to documentation the `onSaveInstaneState()` could be called anytime before `onDestroy()` (it may come after `onStop()`).