# Redirect to particular Activity when launching app from recents

Tags: android, android-activity, android-homebutton

Assume you are in Activity A and press home button now your app will goto background. Now long press your home button and you can see recent's app. If I click my app it should take to particular activity not Activity A.

Comment: Why don't you make your prefered 'starting' Activity your starting Activity (MainActivity)?

Comment: override `onResume` of activity and start witch activity you want, set one flag in `onCreate()` and `onPause()`

Comment: How can I identify user has pressed home button and coming back from recent's? same activity lifecycle methods are called when moving from one activity to another @shayanpourvatan

Comment: when you back to activity from home or other activity `onResume()` has been clled, you can handle in that method

Comment: How to figure out they are coming back from recent or other activity? @shayanpourvatan

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4414171/how-to-detect-when-an-android-app-goes-to-the-background-and-come-back-to-the-fo/9876683#9876683

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With reference of this post - [How can I detect user pressing HOME key in my activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208912/how-can-i-detect-user-pressing-home-key-in-my-activity) have implemented below logic.

Detect Home button press by using above post and store a flag in preferences. While launching app from Recent's list by first OnRestart() method will be fired so check home button pressed flag and launch particular activity.

```
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        if (isApplicationSentToBackground(this)) {
            // Do what you want to do on detecting Home Key being Pressed
             preferences.setHomeButtonPressed(true);
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        super.onRestart();
    // Do what you want to do on detecting app launching from recents section
        if (preferences.isHomeButtonPressed()) {
            Intent i = new Intent(this,
                    ParticularActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            preferences.setHomeButtonPressed(false);
        }

    }

    public static boolean isApplicationSentToBackground(final Context context) {
        ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> tasks = am.getRunningTasks(1);
        if (!tasks.isEmpty()) {
            ComponentName topActivity = tasks.get(0).topActivity;
            if (!topActivity.getPackageName().equals(context.getPackageName())) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think is a strange requirement, but you could do something like this:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
   startActivity(new Intent(this, TargetActivity.class));
}
```

onResume() is called right before your app is in state 'running'

[image]

Comment: this code is wrong, because `onResume()` called in first time and current activity never be running, you must handle that with one flag that set to `false` in `onCreate` and change that to `true` in `onPause` and in onResume chekc `if(flag)` start `TargetActivity`

Comment: It will always start new activity. I want to start an activity when user launching app from recent's only.