# Override Home Button and Back Button in Service - Android

Tags: android, android-service

I need to detect HomeButton event in Service. Not in Activity.

I am making an app which will make overlay on any other App. Like additional menu which is always on top of the screen.
In some specific events I need to override pressing home button, menu button, back button, volume button also power button.

I believe that this must be done in Service, since all other Apps must run normal. So the events must be handled in Service not in Activity.

It is possible:
http://www.kidscrape.com

Comment: sooo, what have you tried so far?

Comment: you want to know, how to detect home button event. RIGHT?

Comment: Not possible in latest api's. http://stackoverflow.com/a/17756786/4596556.  You should come up with new code :)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to find a way how to communicate from the `Activity` to the `Service` (and conversely). The easiest would be to use `EventBus`, either on of these two:

1. http://square.github.io/otto/
2. https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus

So ultimately you just fire an event from `Activity#onBackPressed()` and catch it in the `Service`.