# phonelock not working on click of home,actionbar and recentteb bar

Tags: android

I am making application for phone lock i have some issue in my applicaiton when i press home button, on action bar, or in recent app bar key press applock not work.

I have applied following code for home press but it also did not worked.

```
 @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, android.view.KeyEvent event) {

        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN)
                || (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER)
                || (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP)
                || (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_CAMERA)) {
            return true;
        }
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME)) {
            Log.e("home", "home");
            return true;
        }

        return false;

    }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208912/how-can-i-detect-user-pressing-home-key-in-my-activity

Comment: visit this : http://rdcworld-android.blogspot.in/2012/03/lock-phone-screen-programmtically.html

Comment: it is not working for me i have already tried that ..please help if any one have solution.