# Android Window Class

Tags: android

Is their anyway to not display the bottom menu bar in my app on the tablet?  I was able to get the title bar to disappear using ->

```
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

What class am I looking for? Android 3.0.. Is this feature available in any android version?

Thanks

Comment: Android 3.0 doesn't have any hard keys for navigation. Therefore you can't remove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your device is rooted you can from shell ->

```
service call activity 79 s16 com.android.systemui
```

This functionality will break after reboot obviously so call it from your application.

```
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"su","-c","service call activity 79 s16 com.android.systemui"});
proc.waitFor();
```

Comment: It's a private, unsupported API. If you rely on it, your app will break in a future version of Android.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot remove the bottom bar.

Comment: maybe not on the application level, what about OS? wouldn't this be in the build.props file or something similar?

Comment: You could build a custom version of Android but you would need to distribute your own device :)

Comment: looks like on a rooted device you can `# service call activity 79 s16 com.android.systemui`

Comment: If this works (no idea if it does) this is not a public API and chances are it will break in the next relesae.

Comment: Well if it does, it will likely break in a future version of Android. We change private APIs all the time, sometimes on purpose. You should not rely on this at all.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible in Android 2. Here is a link to a page I found http://sree.cc/google/android/hiding-the-notification-bar-and-title-bar-in-android

As far as I know, there is no way to do this in Android 3.x. What exactly are you trying to achieve by removing the bar?

Comment: Well, I was trying to remove it so It cannot be used to exit the app as I am building a proprietary app that will only run on our devices.

Comment: Maybe their is a way to not allow it to be used instead of removed? also adjust the things that are displayed on the bar?

Comment: You could override the onKeyDown listeners for the buttons possibly.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2079691/overriding-the-home-button-how-do-i-get-rid-of-the-choice