# Android long-press home button

Tags: android, android-homebutton

In my Samsung Galaxy S long-press home button open the stock/samsung task manager. Is there any way to programmatically change the asociated action for this event? I suppose it will not depend on the device, as it looks like an android issue in general. Would like to put another custom task manager

Also I have been looking in the android market for an application that do that, but dont find it, which sounds strange. (there are lot for changing the simple-touch home button action) though.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2079691/overriding-the-home-button-how-do-i-get-rid-of-the-choice

Answer (score 1):

Android will not allow you to do custom actions on pressing  **Home** Button event.  :)

Comment: Unless you make your own launcher, but that's starting to get pretty hacky.

Answer (score 1):

Post ICS i.e. Android 4+, the overriding of the HomeButton has been removed for security reasons, to enable the user exit in case the application turns out to be a malware.

Plus, it is not a really good practice to not let the user navigate away from the application. But, since you are making a lock screen application, what you can do is declare the activity as a **Launcher** , so that when the HomeButton is pressed it will simply restart your application and remain there itself (the users would notice nothing but a slight flicker in the screen).

**EDIT #1 :** Here is [another workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10077675/disable-home-button-in-android-ics-4-0), more suited to your needs.

**EDIT #2 :** Came across [this.](http://dharmendra4android.blogspot.in/2012/05/override-home-button-in-android.html) Haven't tested it. But looks kinda promising. Not sure if it would work, but you could give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

There are apps in the play store that allow you to customise the button such as Home2 Shortcut.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.eikatou0.appspot.home2shortcut