# How do i declare my Activity as Launcher?

Tags: android, manifest, launcher

I am trying to build a kind of custom lockscreen.

In order to achieve that I need to disable the HOME button.

From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12436190/block-home-button-in-ice-cream-sandwich-and-jelly-bean) I understand that I can achieve that by declaring my Activity as a Launcher.

Please how do I do that? (it is in the Manifest obviously)
This is the Manifest.
The Activity that "acts" as a lockscreen is **LockScreen**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.appengine.paranoid_android.lost"
android:versionCode="2"
android:versionName="1.1" >

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".InfoSetup"
        android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
        android:label="@string/activity_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTask" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".LockScreen"
        android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
        android:label="@string/activity_name"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
        <service
            android:name=".InfoService"
            android:label="@string/service_name" />

        <receiver android:name="com.appengine.paranoid_android.lost.BootCompleteReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_CHANGED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED" />

                <data android:scheme="package" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </activity>
</application>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />
<!-- <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD"/> -->
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" >
</uses-sdk>
```

Comment: ya ok.. after andorid os 4.0 you can't lock home button..

Comment: read the doc. you need to answer the HOME category intent with MAIN action

Comment: @njzk2 thank you. But I do not know how to do it or where tor read... I would appreciate if you could give me some more details

Comment: where to read the doc about intents ? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

Comment: also, you cannot declare a service inside an activity in the manifest. these are separated elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the intent filter to your activity

```
<activity
    android:name=".LockScreen"
    android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
    android:label="@string/activity_name"
    android:launchMode="singleInstance"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```