# First Program - No Launcher activity found

Tags: android-activity, launcher

I am struggling to get my first Android application to run. I create a new Android Application Project and ask for a "Blank Activity" on the Create Activity dialog box.

When I run the Dave application as an Android project, I get the following console messages in red:

```
[2014-07-04 22:14:40 - MyFirstProject] No Launcher activity found!
[2014-07-04 22:14:40 - MyFirstProject] The launch will only sync the application package on the device!
```

The Virtual Device shows up, and when I unlock it there is no Dave application.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

you need to declare in your manifest the activity .. and add a category also ..declaring it as a launcher.

like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16710769/how-do-i-declare-my-activity-as-launcher?answertab=votes#tab-top).. it would have been nice if you could just google a little more :)

**code snippet:**

```
<activity
android:name=".YourActivityName"
android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
android:label="@string/activity_name">

<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem with the missing activity and launcher are caused by Eclipse. I found a post [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24469444/android-eclipse-not-creating-blank-activity) where someone else had this kind of problem and fixed it by NOT installing the SDK and Eclipse bundle, but rather installing components separately. Now the new application gets generated properly.