# Activity visible even after pressing home button

Tags: android

When I click on home button, the current activity which is running is still visible and home button doesn't have any effect. While the activity vanishes if I press the back button.

I checked my logs and got this:-

```
01-17 09:12:32.871  2403  2663 IWindowManager: isSystemKeyEventRequested() : keyCode=3 is blocked by componentName=ComponentInfo{com.sec.android.app.myApp}
```

Here KEYCODE_HOME = 3. It doesn't happen everytime. Just once or twice this issue came,but I wanted to know the reason behind it.

How can home button be blocked by an activity?  I am using kitkat.

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12568747/1643188

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4538450/1643188

Perhaps this is just what you want or let´s say how the developer blocked the home button :)

Comment: Thanks for reply. but none of these works for kitkat. And even, i am not seeing any flicker in the screen,and i don't want this app as default launcher..It just happened once,and i captured the logs.Now i am not able to reproduce, although i didn't change the code.