# App not getting minimized on home button click

Tags: android

I want to write some code on Home button clicked by user in my app.

I written following code:

```
 @Override
        public void onAttachedToWindow() {
            super.onAttachedToWindow();
            this.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD);           
        }

     @Override
        public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {     

            if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME)
            {
               //The Code Want to Perform. 
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), flag+"In Here", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
            return true;
        }
```

This code gives me Toast message, but does not minize my app.

Once i remove following code:

```
  @Override
            public void onAttachedToWindow() {
                super.onAttachedToWindow();
                this.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD);           
            }
```

and keep only:

```
 @Override
            public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {     

                if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME)
                {
                   //The Code Want to Perform. 
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), flag+"In Here", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
                return true;
            }
```

It does not shows me toast message.

Please help me.

I also tried:

Return false

Onpause method

but not worked.

Comment: Strange, it should be working by default :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have this code,

```
 @Override
            public void onAttachedToWindow() {
                super.onAttachedToWindow();
                this.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD);           
            }
```

in your code. Removing this will not trigger the Home key action.

Now to minimize the app, do the following,

```
    @Override
                public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {     

                    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME)
                    {
                       //The Code Want to Perform. 
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), flag+"In Here", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 Intent gotoHome= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                 gotoHome.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                 gotoHome.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                 startActivity(gotoHome);
                    }
                    return true;
                }
```

But I think this solution no more works for higher API levels.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#KEYCODE_HOME. is it possible? its handled by the framework

Comment: i don't think it possible http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13139970/override-home-key-in-android-ics

Comment: @AndroSelva oh ok i din't see the last part

Comment: @NavatKayAahe even if it works its not recommended. Why do you need that?

Comment: @Raghunandan boss told me, i m new with this tech, i dont know harms in it, i just have to make my app running till 8 o clock :)

Answer (score 2):

Try `return false` instead so you don't catch the click event but sends it along to the OS as well.

Answer (score 2):

Returning true in onKeyDown signals that the event has been processed.

Modify your code to `return false` so that the event is further processed by the OS.

For example:

```
        public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {     

            if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME)
            {
               //The Code Want to Perform. 
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), flag+"In Here", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
            return false; // Signals the KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME to be processed further.
        }
```

See the [onKeyDown](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onKeyDown%28int,%20android.view.KeyEvent%29) documentation