# Android app is not shown in minimized list after home button pressed

Tags: android, minimization

I'm trying to write an android app.
It works fine so far, except
when I'm pressing the home button, the app disappears and is not shown in the list of all the minimized apps (what does usually happen).
How can I change it to work normally?

Comment: Have you by chance changed the onPause() method?

Comment: No, I didn't touch it.

Comment: One more thing, when I start the app again from apps gallery it resumed and not restarted, so onPause() works fine.

Comment: which device are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solved it, finally. Apparently, in my strings.xml the app_name was empty. In this case, the app won't show in recent apps list.
Maybe it will save time to someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Thats must be done automatically, I do not if you are doing something with home button. Anyway I let you this link, maybe could help you.

[App not getting minimized on home button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18487691/app-not-getting-minimized-on-home-button-click)

Comment: Thanks, I have seen this answer, but I am not touching home button and not using any of this functions. I wonder if this behavior is maybe configurable in manifest file or somewhere.