# How to override home button in android 4.0

Tags: android, overriding, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-homebutton

I want to override the home button in my android activity. I have tried out few things related to this which are working for 2.3 and below but not for 4.0 above

```
@Override public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME)
    {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, ActivityB.class));
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event); }
```

and other is way

```
 @Override public void onAttachedToWindow() { 
     this.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD);
     super.onAttachedToWindow(); 
 }
```

But its not helping me. any have idea about it please share information

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10025660/override-home-and-back-button-is-case-a-boolean-is-true/10025904#10025904

Comment: <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />

Comment: There is no way to intercept the home button on Android , unless you make your app the home screen.  If you want to handle the HOME button, implement a home screen.

Comment: you can't. but why do you want to

Comment: @Raghunandan: That what the requirement says. and i want know if it not possible then why its is so?

Comment: @Balu for security reasons so that malacious apps d not take control

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disable Home Button in Android ICS (4.0)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10077675/disable-home-button-in-android-ics-4-0)

Answer (score 4):

I also encountered such a problem and I am using the following class to listen to the home button click event.

```
public class HomeWatcher {

    static final String TAG = "HomeWatcher";

    private Context mContext;

    private IntentFilter mFilter;

    private OnHomePressedListener mListener;

    private InnerRecevier mRecevier;

    public HomeWatcher(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        mFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS);
    }

    /**
     * set the home pressed listener, if set will callback the home pressed
     * listener's method when home pressed.
     * 
     * @param listener
     */
    public void setOnHomePressedListener(OnHomePressedListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
        mRecevier = new InnerRecevier();
    }

    /**
     * start watch
     */
    public void startWatch() {
        if (mRecevier != null) {
            mContext.registerReceiver(mRecevier, mFilter);
        }
    }

    /**
     * stop watch
     */
    public void stopWatch() {
        if (mRecevier != null) {
            mContext.unregisterReceiver(mRecevier);
        }
    }

    class InnerRecevier extends BroadcastReceiver {

        final String SYSTEM_DIALOG_REASON_KEY = "reason";

        final String SYSTEM_DIALOG_REASON_GLOBAL_ACTIONS = "globalactions";

        final String SYSTEM_DIALOG_REASON_RECENT_APPS = "recentapps";

        final String SYSTEM_DIALOG_REASON_HOME_KEY = "homekey";

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (action.equals(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS)) {
                String reason = intent.getStringExtra(SYSTEM_DIALOG_REASON_KEY);
                if (reason != null) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "receive action:" + action + ",reason:" + reason);
                    if (mListener != null) {
                        if (reason.equals(SYSTEM_DIALOG_REASON_HOME_KEY)) {

                            // home?
                            mListener.onHomePressed();
                        } else if (reason
                                .equals(SYSTEM_DIALOG_REASON_RECENT_APPS)) {

                            // ??home?
                            mListener.onHomeLongPressed();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Usage is as follows:

```
HomeWatcher mHomeWatcher = new HomeWatcher(Context);
mHomeWatcher.setOnHomePressedListener(new OnHomePressedListener() {

    public void onHomePressed() {

        //do your somthing...
    }

    public void onHomeLongPressed() {
    }

});

mHomeWatcher.startWatch();
```