# How to add a listener to home button?

Tags: android

How to add a listener to home button? i.e I want to add some functionality when home button is pressed. How do I do it?
I did the following, but it is not working for home button. It's working only for back button.

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
    {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
        {
                   // some functionality

    }

    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME)
    {

        // some functionality

    }

    // // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);

}
```

Comment: maybe you can elaborate on your intentions. :)

Comment: this answer can help you to resolver it http://stackoverflow.com/a/31340960/6649041

Answer (score 1):

don't do that. its not correct to do that because the only use of home button is to exit from the application at any point. you can use `isFinishing()` if u want to execute any code while leaving an activity. have a look into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2079691/overriding-the-home-button-how-do-i-get-rid-of-the-choice).

Answer (score 1):

You must override `onAttachedToWindow()` first.

```
@Override
    public void onAttachedToWindow() {
        this.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD); 
        super.onAttachedToWindow();
    }
```

In addition, you need to add the permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD "></uses-permission>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. The Android policy forbids that a App can overwrite or listen to the Homebutton. 
Maybe you can accomplish what you want with overwriting `onDetachFromWindow`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't but you could use onPause(). The application will be paused when the home button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

> How to add a listener to home button?

You don't. The HOME button always brings up the user's chosen home screen. You can elect to make your app be a home screen, by supporting `CATEGORY_HOME` in an activity, but then it had better really work as a home screen.