# Android: associate a method to home button of smartphone

Tags: java, android, home-button

how can I associate a method to home button of smartphone? I want that checking this botton my Android app does a specific method. I read that to disable home button there is the method:

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

but it isn't useful for me. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: you can't because it would change the standard behavior of an Android phone

Comment: I want that, when the user is using my app, clicks the home button, there is the logout from my app

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use this code:

```
HomeWatcher mHomeWatcher = new HomeWatcher(this);
mHomeWatcher.setOnHomePressedListener(new OnHomePressedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onHomePressed() {
        // do something here...
    }
    @Override
    public void onHomeLongPressed() {
    }
});
mHomeWatcher.startWatch();
```

HomeWatcher:

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.util.Log;

public class HomeWatcher {

    static final String TAG = "hg";
    private Context mContext;
    private IntentFilter mFilter;
    private OnHomePressedListener mListener;
    private InnerRecevier mRecevier;

    public HomeWatcher(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        mFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS);
    }

    public void setOnHomePressedListener(OnHomePressedListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
        mRecevier = new InnerRecevier();
    }

    public void startWatch() {
        if (mRecevier != null) {
            mContext.registerReceiver(mRecevier, mFilter);
        }
    }

    public void stopWatch() {
        if (mRecevier != null) {
            mContext.unregisterReceiver(mRecevier);
        }
    }

    class InnerRecevier extends BroadcastReceiver {
        final String SYSTEM_DIALOG_REASON_KEY = "reason";
        final String SYSTEM_DIALOG_REASON_GLOBAL_ACTIONS = "globalactions";
        final String SYSTEM_DIALOG_REASON_RECENT_APPS = "recentapps";
        final String SYSTEM_DIALOG_REASON_HOME_KEY = "homekey";

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (action.equals(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS)) {
                String reason = intent.getStringExtra(SYSTEM_DIALOG_REASON_KEY);
                if (reason != null) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "action:" + action + ",reason:" + reason);
                    if (mListener != null) {
                        if (reason.equals(SYSTEM_DIALOG_REASON_HOME_KEY)) {
                            mListener.onHomePressed();
                        } else if (reason.equals(SYSTEM_DIALOG_REASON_RECENT_APPS)) {
                            mListener.onHomeLongPressed();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

OnHomePressedListener:

```
public interface OnHomePressedListener {
    public void onHomePressed();

    public void onHomeLongPressed();
}
```

Comment: this is throws "Activity has leaked IntentReceiver HomeWatcher$InnerReceiver@2a49226 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()"  how to solve this error????

Comment: @PankajTalaviya Call mHomeWatcher.stopWatch() in a suitable place

Comment: mContext.registerReceiver(mRecevier, mFilter); induces crash "SecurityException: One of RECEIVER_EXPORTED or RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED should be specified when a receiver isn't being registered exclusively for system broadcasts" Any idea how to solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

Try overriding onKeyDown as such:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME)
        // do what you need
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use This Code For only HomeWtcher class this one is better.

```
public class HomeWatcher {

    static final String TAG = "hg";
    private Context mContext;
    private IntentFilter mFilter;
    private OnHomePressedListener mListener;
    private InnerReceiver mReceiver;

    public HomeWatcher(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        mFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS);
    }

    public void setOnHomePressedListener(OnHomePressedListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
        mReceiver = new InnerReceiver();
    }

    public void startWatch() {
        if (mReceiver != null) {
            mContext.registerReceiver(mReceiver, mFilter);
        }
    }

    public void stopWatch() {
        if (mReceiver != null) {
            mContext.unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
        }
    }

    class InnerReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        final String SYSTEM_DIALOG_REASON_KEY = "reason";
        final String SYSTEM_DIALOG_REASON_GLOBAL_ACTIONS = "globalactions";
        final String SYSTEM_DIALOG_REASON_RECENT_APPS = "recentapps";
        final String SYSTEM_DIALOG_REASON_HOME_KEY = "homekey";

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (action.equals(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS)) {
                String reason = intent.getStringExtra(SYSTEM_DIALOG_REASON_KEY);
                if (reason != null) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "action:" + action + ",reason:" + reason);
                    if (mListener != null) {
                        if (reason.equals(SYSTEM_DIALOG_REASON_HOME_KEY)) {
                            mListener.onHomePressed();
                        } else if (reason.equals(SYSTEM_DIALOG_REASON_RECENT_APPS)) {
                            mListener.onHomeLongPressed();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: mContext.registerReceiver(mRecevier, mFilter); induces crash "SecurityException: One of RECEIVER_EXPORTED or RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED should be specified when a receiver isn't being registered exclusively for system broadcasts" Any idea how to solve it ?