# Prevent activity from exiting

Tags: android

I like to know how to prevent an activity from exiting if the user presses the back and the home button?

Comment: there's no way to override home button. you can't lock user to stay on your application. it's the same way on all mobile devices. look iPhone, also no way to prevent from exiting application when presses home button. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2079691/overriding-the-home-button-how-do-i-get-rid-of-the-choice

Comment: you can refer this link http://nisha113a5.blogspot.in/2012/01/intercept-home-key-android.html to intercept home button key.

Comment: I'm doing kind of a lockscreen right after the mobile boots.therefore i do think there is a way to override home button. but thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use:

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {
            // don't write anything here to make back button not work
            return true;
        }

        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

or you can use the `onBackPressed()` but older version doesn't support this feature.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
// don't write anything here to make back button  not work
}
```

Comment: please tick the check icon if this answers your question. :)

Answer (score 2):

Overriding these buttons is a dangerous/bad idea and for that reason the home button can't be truly overridden permanently without the user confirming it. See this discussion: [Overriding the Home button - how do I get rid of the choice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2079691/overriding-the-home-button-how-do-i-get-rid-of-the-choice)

The back button is a bit easier, just override onBackPressed:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
//do nothing
}
```