# How to show layout over all screens?

Tags: android

In some cases my app should show block screen. This screen pop up over alll screens, cover all UI elements and doesn't react on presses on back and home button, but should have ability to input password into.

Could you please suggest me a way how I can do that?

Comment: I sincerely hope this isn't possible.

Comment: Sounds to me like he wants to do a passcode Activity for his own app, what's the problem with that?

Comment: As a user I would like to be able to navigate away from that, perhaps even related to this! For example launching or switching to my email/browser/talk/skype application where my passcode can be found. And then return to this screen.

Comment: You will have a chance to turn off this functionality from settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll ignore the question of *why* you would want to do this, and just focus on the how.
If you want to display UI full screen over all other screens, you will need to use an system alert window. 
You will need permissions [SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW), and set your window type to

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT
```

Answer (score 1):

You really shouldn't even try that. **The user should be in control of his own phone.** If I want to check my email, see my notifications, swap to another app or whatever I should be able to do so whenever I can.

Having said that: blocking the back button can be done by overriding this method in your activity (to do nothing for example)

```
public void onBackPressed() {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create fullscreen `Activity` with transparent background, put your "input password info" logic, `override` *"Home"* and *"BackButton"* actions in that *Activity*.

But this is not the best `Android` practice.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but as I know it is bossible to override back button not there is no way to do it for Home button

Comment: it is possible too to override the event click on HomeButton

Comment: Could you please provide an example how to do that?

Comment: Overriding Home button is dangerous for security reasons, but your can read this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2079691/overriding-the-home-button-how-do-i-get-rid-of-the-choice