# How to stop my app from exiting when back/home button button is pressed?

Tags: android, back-button, android-homebutton

I am making an app exclusive for the tablet it was installed to. I wanted to put a restriction so that when the back button or home button is pressed the user will be prompted to enter a password and if the password is correct application be allowed to exit.

Comment: you can override onPause() method to do this

Comment: Please don't, that would be horrible UX !

Comment: @2Dee the app will be exclusive to the tablet it was installed to

Answer (score 2):

Overriding the back button is pretty easy, just override Activity.onBackPressed() to do whatever you want. Don't call super() or it will close the Activity!

Overriding the home button is more problematic. The only way to do so is to [make your app a launcher](http://arnab.ch/blog/2013/08/how-to-write-custom-launcher-app-in-android/). Then press home and select your app as the default launcher.

Comment: thanks for this.. this is a big help. yes, the home button is really problematic. if the app is made as a launcher, how do i revert to the old launcher? is that entirely possible?

Comment: @ChristianBurgos yes, totally. Just go into the settings, application, "your-app", clear defaults.

Comment: how about this, if the app is the chosen default launcher then how am i gonna go the settings?

Comment: @ChristianBurgos that's why I don't think this approach will work. You should rethink the flow. One could be the one I suggested.

Comment: @ChristianBurgos I know an app can programmatically deregister itself as the default launcher, but I don't know how. I know it's possible because this app does it: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.whisperarts.kidsshell)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that this could be a good idea. You're "blocking" the user in this way. You can probably override the back button but you will not be able to [override the home button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2079691/overriding-the-home-button-how-do-i-get-rid-of-the-choice) (without making the app a launcher).

I did a sort of "kiosk" application and I had the same requirements. I ended up **rooting** the devices and using this **[Hide Bar](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=be.ppareit.hidebar)** application. The user was not able to go back, and the administrator had a button to enter, with a password, into the "admin panel". In this admin panel you can push a button to go to the launcher. From there you can, with a widget included into the Hide Bar app, restore the back and home buttons.

Comment: You can totally override the home button. See my answer.

Comment: @BarryFruitman you're not really overriding it. You're creating a launcher. I don't think that, pressing the home button, the user will be happy to be prompted to use "Sense" or "MyNiceBlockingApp" as new launcher.

Comment: the app will be exclusive to the hardware/tablet it was installed to.

Comment: @Enrichman That's why I said he would have to do it manually the first time.

Answer (score 1):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html

May be this can help you for setting the passoward.