# How to disable home button like 'cover' app?

Tags: android, lockscreen, android-homebutton

As far as I know, there is no way to disable 'Home button' in android system. 
But recently, I found a locker 'cover'.
Just install it, but the home button does not work.
How is this possible?

Comment: The first hit on Google: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17549478/how-to-disable-home-and-other-system-buttons-in-android

Answer (score 1):

In privious android versions it was possible to override HOME Button using :

keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME

but now its not possible. Android will not let you override its behavior the same way you do the BACK button.

Still, the link below will give you good idea of it.

[Overriding the Home button - how do I get rid of the choice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2079691/overriding-the-home-button-how-do-i-get-rid-of-the-choice)

Hope it helps.