# How to know when the camera app is closed in android?

Tags: android, android-camera

I have an activity that starts the camera app in secure mode using :

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.INTENT_ACTION_STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA_SECURE);
```

I need to do some processing after the camera app is gone. So in the `onResume()` , I had written the code to handle the POST processing (This is because, let say the camera app is launched in ParentActivity, then after camera app finishes, the `onResume()` of ParentActivity will be called). The program is working fine for the camera closing via `Back` button but when the camera is closed by `Home` button or `Recent` button, the POST processing is not getting called. So where can I place the code of POST processing that will get called everytime the user moves away from the camera (via `Home` , `Recent`, `Back` buttons) . I cant change the camera activity code as the camera application is not written by me , so I can't put the POST processing inside the `onPause()` of the camera activity. Is there anyway, I can override the `onPause()` of an Activity that I am starting by `startActivity` ?

Comment: If the user navigates away from the camera app without taking a picture, what do you have to post-process, since you will not have a picture?

Comment: The camera is a part of Lockscreen, so even when the user walks away from the camera withouyt doing anything, I have to reenable the lock screen

Comment: Take a look at this thread (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2079691/overriding-the-home-button-how-do-i-get-rid-of-the-choice) it could give you some infos