# How can we lock HOME KEY BACK KEY and MENU KEY in Android Lollipop and Higher

Tags: android, onbackpressed

how can we lock  HOME KEY   BACK KEY and MENU KEY in android Lollipop and Higher

I have a Transparent activity which has some paint functionality

while the activity is being used, I want to disable the 
`HOME KEY   BACK KEY and MENU KEY` in Android lollipop  and higher how can this be done

back press can be disabled using

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
}
```

disabling home key was possible earlier but not supported now

how can this be done?

Comment: don't call super.onBackPressed

Answer (score 0):

Overriding the home and back button is not allowed since it is the only way a user can be guaranteed to leave the app. I'd advice you to take a look at [this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2079691/overriding-the-home-button-how-do-i-get-rid-of-the-choice)