# My app crashes on trying to disable home button

Tags: android, android-activity, crash, android-actionbar, android-homebutton

I've been trying to disable the home button using the following code:

```
 @Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME) {
        Log.i("TAG", "Press Home");
        System.exit(0);
        return true;
    } else {
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}

@Override
public void onAttachedToWindow() {    
  this.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD_DIALOG);
  super.onAttachedToWindow();}      

}
```

But this crashes the app.

The crash is caused specifically by the line:

```
this.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD_DIALOG);
```

Why does this happen? What can be done to solve this issue?

The crash Log:

```
06-25 17:47:18.620 18125-18125/com.example.myapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                      Process: com.example.nandagp.qapp, PID: 18125
                                                                      java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Window type can not be changed after the window is added.
                                                                          at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1962)
                                                                          at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1904)
                                                                          at android.view.IWindowSession$Stub$Proxy.relayout(IWindowSession.java:966)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl.relayoutWindow(ViewRootImpl.java:7029)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2264)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1738)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7745)
                                                                          at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:911)
                                                                          at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:723)
                                                                          at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:658)
                                                                          at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:897)
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

Comment: add the error log

Comment: Please post the full crash log.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko Sorry, but how is this a duplicate of the mentioned post? I'm requesting the app crash reason for a specific function.Please remove the dupicate tag and the down vote.

Comment: @PierGiorgioMisley error log posted.

Comment: @Rohit5k2 error log posted

Comment: That question was not going to solve your problem, but to give you an idea about how you should organize your question about app crash. Main idea is that **you have to provide exception stacktrace**

Comment: I'm sorry, I had forgotten to add it. It's added now.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove this code

```
this.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD_DIALOG);
```

From the `onAttachedToWindow()` method and put it into the `onCreate` one.

Hope this helps

PS: for the home button override, [read this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2079691/overriding-the-home-button-how-do-i-get-rid-of-the-choice). Disabling it is not easy and not reccomended, it will result in user unable to exit your application and (imo) it is not a good idea unless you are running in [kiosk mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068084/kiosk-mode-in-android). So think accurately if you really need to do it and, if you do, refer to the first link I posted

Comment: It stops the app crash but doesn't disable the home button.

Comment: @Nandgopal added a couple of rows

Comment: That post gives a similar answer as well.

Comment: @Nandgopal why should you override the home button?

Comment: I need to prevent the user from closing the app or moving to another, from that activity. I have been able to disable the back button and the recent apps button. Is there a way to remove the actionbar instead?

Comment: you can do it by editing the theme in your style file and using noactionbar one

Comment: I tried that. It is causing the app to crash as well.

Comment: check again on the web, there are many answers.. or also post a new question and close/solve this

Comment: I would prefer an answer to this question, as finding a way to disable the home button would be my choice, as i need the other 2 buttons to perform other actions. Removing the actionbar is just my last resort.

Comment: refer to the other link for this, simply you can't just do it but you have to manage the entire home state.. You can't create a normal app that overrides the home button, this would have no sense since the user would not be allowed to go back to the home. It's like if you invite someone at your home and allow him to change the door lock whenever he wants, would you do this?

Comment: Only one specific activity needs the home button disabled. This activity has other buttons that allow the user to go to other activities where home button is enabled.

Comment: yes, but it's like saying "if you are in my kitchen, you can change the door lock". As you can understand, it is better to always say no than to say "sometimes yes". Expecially because if you wrongly manage this, the user will be locked in forever.. not a good idea to allow this

Comment: This app is not for general users or for public use. It is for a very specific set of users. All i need is a solution to this or to understand why the crash happens.

Comment: google doesn't care at all of your final use, they just don't want this to appen. Then if you sell your app to anyone or if you only use that when you are in your bathroom, for them is the exact same stuff.. If you want to do this, create a launcher app or a kiosk mode

Answer (score 0):

When user pressed "KEYCODE_HOME" you "shutdown" application:

```
if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME) {
        Log.i("TAG", "Press Home");
        System.exit(0);
```

You will be delete System.exit(0)

Comment: It doesn't. Deleting that doesn't still crashes the app.