# Disable Android Home Button (Not Hardware Button)

Tags: android, android-homebutton

How Could We disable Home Buttons in Android devices. (Not Hardware Buttons, Touch Screen Buttons).I Can Disable Hardware Home Buttons But... Anyone Have Solution For this?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot override the home button, for security reasons. I would recommend looking at this this answer on another thread:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2080353/9699953

Comment: But I seen one Software which disabling Home Button...Thats Why im Curious How They Done it

Comment: Can you send the one software please?