# how to add AlertDialog in OnPause() method?

Tags: java, android, onpause

I want to show an `AlertDialog` when a user click on Back, Home and Recent button in Android Navigation Bar for back button.

I used `onBackPressed()` method and it's working fine but for Home and Recent, I am using `onPause()` method and it's not working.

Kindly help me to resolve it.

```
@Override
    public void onPause() {
        builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Alert")
                .setMessage("Do you want to close application?")
                .setCancelable(true)
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        finish();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        dialogInterface.cancel();
                    }
                })
                .show();
         super.onPause();
    }
```

Comment: Don't call `super.onPause();`

Comment: it shows error when i dont call super.OnPause();

Comment: You can't intercept home and recent buttons.

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons, Android wont let you override the default home button that easily, take a look at this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2079691/overriding-the-home-button-how-do-i-get-rid-of-the-choice)